# Fastest way to search for a pixel specific pixel in an image

Tags: image, algorithm, optimization

What is the fastest way to search for a specific pixel in an image?
The image file size is 16 MB.From an algorithm perspective I don't think I can get better than a linear search.
I've tried to split the image in 2 quadrants 1 for each CPU and to load the image in memory and read it from there.
Is there anything else I can do ?

Comment: Are you going to do multiple searches on the image or just the one?

Comment: One time.I need to count how many times a specific color appears

Comment: What is the file format? If it is compressed (e.g. run length encoded) then you can speed things up by counting the pixels as you decompress it rather than decompressing the whole thing and then iterating over the image. You don't even need to store the decompressed results either.

Comment: Saying that the file is 16MB doesn't tell us what the dimensions are or how many bits per pixel you have. It could be a huge image of very compressible greyscale data, or a small image very incompressible colour data.

Comment: Please supply width and height of image and details of whether colour or grayscale, 8- or 16-bit and whether JPEG, PNG or TIFF.

Comment: 16-bit JPEG color

Answer (score 1):

Quadrants are actually a bit annoying, they can help when there's something spatial going on but since this is just a linear search all they do is break up the nice sequential access pattern. So you should just divide the image in 1D slices of memory, ignoring the original 2D-ness of the data.

In addition, check whether your code is being autovectorized by the compiler, and if it isn't (or even if it is but improvement is possible), manually vectorize with SIMD intrinsics. 24bpp would make that a bit annoying, but you can deal with it by loading 48 bytes and then redistributing that over 4 vector registers with some shuffling. 32bpp is very easy, just apply (assuming you're targeting x86) `_mm_cmpeq_epi32` between the pixels and the colour you want to find and subtract the result from the count.

Comment: This is the way to go. If you look at the OpenCV function `InRange()` it does more or less what you want and is coded in intrinsics here... https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Usually not, the only thing which can improve:

If for your application is an advantage when you get early results before the exact result is found, you can improve as follows, but this effort may not be worth the time you invest:

**Step 1**: search in steps of 2 or 3 pixels. do further search only when colors are similar. if found return pixel.
  If not found do
**Step 2**:
search the rest of the pixels, (that you overjumped in step1)

But since the calculation of color similarity will exceed the gain of overumping some pixels, this algo shows that a linear search will most probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some approximation strategy to prune/skip some range of pixels where the chance of finding specific pixel is less likely. But if you end up performing linear search, you can certainly optimize the seeking time on disk by [Loop Blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling). By this way, you can make the best use of main memory and reduce disk lookup.

You can also see Intel's article [improve memory utilization by means of loop blocking](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-loop-blocking-to-optimize-memory-use-on-32-bit-intel-architecture)